# Using jQuery within http.open

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function whichh looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#id').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('pid');
        var title = $(this).attr('ptitle');
    $('#product_list').prepend('<input type="hidden" value="'+ id +'"/><div>'+ title +'</div>')
    });
});
</script>
```

I have a javascript file which has this code here:

```
> http.open('get', 'livesearch.php?name='+searchq+'&nocache =
> '+nocache+'&type=bookings/products');
```

The livesearch.php file has the a element (which the jQuery is requesting) like this:

```
<a href="#" id="id" ptitle="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>" pid="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">Add</a>
```

However when I click on the a element the jQuery doesn't respond. Could any please help?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: How are the javsacript file and the jquery function connected ? And why are you not using the jquery $.get method instead of doing a http.open ?

Comment: Because the JavaScript file is from a different developer. It is a live search engine so whenever I type in a query the http.open is loaded with results,  however when I click on a result it should create a hidden form (as seen in the jquery code shown above).           The jquery is in seperate script tags and the live search is in a in a extenral file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either live or  delegate to add the click event because the element is not present in the DOM at the time the event is bound.

```
$('#id').live('click', function(e){
        alert('you clicked the id element' ); 
});
```

Comment: It's not doing anything. All it does is take me to the top of the page and add the # to the url. Is it maybe something to do with the prepend part of the code?

Comment: Sorry i didn't fully write out the .live part. See what happens now.